# How to show page from a php file using jQuery/Ajax in Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm tring to show a chart in the default about page using ajax.

I have a php class that draws the charts and displays them correctly, But in order for them to be drawn I have to send some parameters to the function I created. 
So to make it more responsive I decided to use AJAX and jQuery to do this. But the way I used to do this without a framework doesn't work.

I know there is a way to do it in yii2 but I'm not too familiar with the framework and don't know exactly how this is supposed to be done, and there are almost no examples of this on the internet.

This is one of the things I've tried thus far:

**This is my form**

```
<form id="chartAttributeSelection">
<label class="control-label" for="contactform-subject">Seleccione la fecha de inicio del periodo de su consulta</label>
<select id='startYear' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=2017>2017</option>
    </select>
<select id='startMonth' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    ...
    <option value=12>12</option>
</select>
<select id='startDay' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    ...
    <option value=31>31</option>
</select>
<label class="control-label" for="contactform-subject">Seleccione la fecha de término del periodo de su consulta</label>
<select id='endYear' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=2017>2017</option>
</select>
<select id='endMonth' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    ...
    <option value=12>12</option>
</select>
<select id='endDay' class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    ...
    <option value=31>31</option>
</select>
<label class="control-label" for="contactform-subject">Seleccione las unidades de su consulta:</label>
<select id="unitType" name="unitType" class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>>
    <option value="w">Watts</option>
    <option value="a">Amperes</option>
    <option value="v">Volts</option>
</select>
<label class="control-label" for="contactform-subject">Seleccione el tipo de consulta:</label>
<select id="calcType" name="calcType" class='form-control' style='width: 30%;'>>
    <option value="a">Promedio</option>
    <option value="s">Total</option>
</select>
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="submitDate">Consultar</a>
</p>
```

**And I tried this js to do the job:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitDate').click(function(event) {
        $('#Charts').html("starting");//I use this as a means to know if the function is even working
        $.post('ChartDisplay.php', { 
            startYear: $('#startYear').val(), 
            startMonth:$('#startMonth').val(),
            startDay:$('#startDay').val(),
            endYear:$('#endYear').val(),
            endMonth:$('#endMonth').val(),
            endDay:$('#endDay').val(),
            unitType:$('#unitType').val(),
            calcType:$('#calcType').val()
        }, function(data) {
                $('#Charts').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I'm only interested in getting the data from the php I'm submitting and displaying it in a div like this one:

```
<div id="Charts"></div>
```

Comment: Have you've tried jQuery's `load` method? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: No but I also tried the things shoen in this example[1], but it since the sample source code is lacking I can't recreate the php classes accurately.
[1]http://www.yiiplayground.com/yii2/web/index.php?r=ajax/index

Comment: Did you use a certain `plugin` that would show that certain `chart`?

Comment: We created the chart using a bundle in jquery, a php class to render the chart using the info stored in a mysql DB, it then echoes the the data to a jQuery function that displays the data in charts. Then the jquery code just prints it to the <div></div>

Those Charts work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: "and there are almost no examples of this on the internet": please look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

You're posting to User.php.

create an action in your controller, say SiteController

`public function actionChart() {
    ... your logic.
}`

make sure you put the right accessRules so you will not run into a 403.

Usually, you would post to a route, say. `/site/chart`

In PHP, create url URL using

`$url = Url::toRoute('/site/chart');` make sure you use the right namespace at the top of your file.

in your JS write:

`$.post('<?= $url ?>')` to get the URL right.

Comment: I will check this out, PD: the User.php was there because of a test I was making, the actual php is called ChartDisplay.php